# How to reduce video size with Java's Monte Screen Recorder

Tags: java, video-capture

I'm recording my screen using Monte Screen Recorder, but the output files are huge. I think I could reduce the file size using MP4 H.264 or maybe turning the video bit rate down somehow. However, I have no idea how to change those settings. Maybe I need to use a secondary java library to convert the file then delete the original? Anyone have any ideas on the best way to do this. Here is how I'm initializing the ScreenRecorder:

```
screenLogger = new ScreenRecorder(gc, null,
                new Format(MediaTypeKey, MediaType.FILE, MimeTypeKey, MIME_AVI),
                new Format(MediaTypeKey, MediaType.VIDEO, EncodingKey, ENCODING_AVI_TECHSMITH_SCREEN_CAPTURE,
                        CompressorNameKey, ENCODING_AVI_TECHSMITH_SCREEN_CAPTURE,
                        DepthKey, 24, FrameRateKey, Rational.valueOf(15),
                        QualityKey, 1.0f,
                        KeyFrameIntervalKey, 15 * 60),
                new Format(MediaTypeKey, MediaType.VIDEO, EncodingKey, "black",
                        FrameRateKey, Rational.valueOf(30)),
                null, new File(pathToFile));
```